# PHP remote file upload using cURL

Tags: php, curl

I have this PHP code which posts a file to upload to a remote server:

```
$filename  = $at[attachment];
$handle    = fopen($filename, "r");
$data      = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
$POST_DATA = array(
'file' => base64_encode($data), 
'location' => 'billing/voip_daily_cdr_files'
);
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.domain.co.uk/file_upload.php');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $POST_DATA);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close ($curl);
```

then the file_upload.php looks like:

```
$encoded_file = $_POST['file'];
$decoded_file = base64_decode($encoded_file);
file_put_contents($_POST["location"].'/'.$decoded_file, $decoded_file);
```

I have done a var_dump($response); to see the output and see this:

```
Warning: file_put_contents(public_html/admin/billing/voip_daily_cdr_files/): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/user/public_html/admin/file_upload.php on line 4
```

am i doing the location incorrect to upload the file to?

Comment: Two things to consider: (1) is the target location in a subdirectory of the directory in which `file_upload.php` is located?
(2) Do all subfolders exist? `file_put_contents` doesn't create subfolders automatically, so you would have to ensure the directory structure beforehand.

Comment: Also, in `file_upload.php` you use `$decoded_file` as the file name (first parameter) *and* as the file content (second parameter).

Comment: file_upload.php is located at /public_html/admin/file_upload.php and the directory to upload into (which does exist) is /public_html/admin/billing/voip_daily_cdr_files/

Comment: Okay, the file path seems to be correct, but you still use `$decoded_file` as the file name. Could you try sending `$filename` along with the other `$_POST` variables and then do `file_put_contents($_POST["location"] . '/' . $_POST["filename"], $decoded_file);`?

Comment: I am not talking about the validation/sanitization of the posted variables at the moment, but you should keep that in mind - you should treat all data sent to your file_upload.php as insecure.

Comment: so what does the location need to be?

Answer (score 0):

use file_get_contents('php://input') to get post data

```
<?php
     $encoded_file  = file_get_contents('php://input');// this is you for getting post data
     print_r($encoded_file );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

file path "public_html/admin/billing/voip_daily_cdr_files/" is not correct try this 
"/billing/voip_daily_cdr_files" if is not work you should check right file path.

Comment: look in my code, thats the path i have but the warning/error is showing this path

Comment: where is billing directory if it in public_html change `''location' => 'billing/voip_daily_cdr_files'`
to `'location' => 'public_html/billing/voip_daily_cdr_files'` .

Comment: directory structure is /public_html/admin/billing/voip_daily_cdr_files/

Comment: tried that path too in the code but still the same error saying it cannot find the directory

Comment: where is billing directory ?

Comment: /public_html/admin/billing/voip_daily_cdr_files/

Comment: file_upload.php is /public_html/admin/file_upload.php

Comment: oh you try to make file with content ? if that true change file_upload.php  to `$myfile = fopen($_POST["location"].'/'.$decoded_file, "w");fwrite($myfile,$decoded_file);fclose($myfile)` and check if $_POST["file"] is null or no .